# How can I send the character q to GIT from batch file

Tags: batch-file, git-bash

I need to show the last commit of my repository from a script for what I'm using:

```
git log -1 --pretty=oneline
```

And here come the questions:

1. One line prints the entire commit hash, due to want to print with this format.

   `git log -1 --pretty=format:%h\ %s\ %an`

   But part of this code inside a batch file is recognized as variable because of `%` signs.
2. In order to finish showing the log, it is necessary to send the character `q`, which works perfectly when typed directly to git bash, but when send from the batch file I get "'q' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: Note: in a windows batch script, `%%h %%s %%an` would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are forcing the use of the pager when issuing commands such as `git log`, if there is no controlling terminal, the command will not use a pager which requires you to type `q` to quit the pager.

You can test what I am describing here by using, say:

```
git log -1 --pretty=oneline | cat
```

Note the use of `cat` at the end of the command above.

If `git` still requires you to type a `q`, then you have to see if you don't have any configuration file (either global--`~/.gitconfig`--or local--`.git/config`) that is forcing git to use the pager.

You can circumvent (without changing the configuration files) the behavior of git by using something like:

```
GIT_PAGER= git log -1 --pretty=oneline
```

Note the space between the equal sign and `git`.

Regarding the percent signs, you probably have to give more details about your environment, as I can't see the percent signs being interpreted as variables by bash itself.

Comment: The use of "| cat" solved the problem, Thanks rbrito. Sorry i'm working in a batch file to show the commit.

Comment: @JavierChauvin, if you think that the answer was useful, upvote it/choose it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

as for the "q" question:

```
git --no-pager
```